# Set "type" for column in datatable dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to show either currency or percent in lwc datatable based on another field. Not able to set type dynamically .Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you mean component field, then you can update your `columns` attribute and it'll rerender in different format, based on logic you specified.

If you are talking about having `currency or percent` based on values in the same row, then you need to create a Custom Type for dataTable, then take a look into documentation for it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation